# If I set a multimeter on 'ohms' and put it across a battery, does it short the battery?

Tags: batteries, multimeter

As the title says. I am not very good at electronics (I might have, uh, actually done this, for no good reason...). I am wondering now if I should be worried about the battery being damaged.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the meter and the battery. To measure resistance your multimeter actually applies some known voltage and measures the resulting current. Although it would be possible to discharge a small battery like a coin cell, I would guess that you are more likely to damage the meter.

Comment: The battery is an 11.1V 2200mah LiPo. The meter's needle shot to max and I took it off immediately, but I know even just a momentary short can cause damage so I am trying to figure out if it was actually a short or not. I had the meter set to 1K ohm range.

Comment: I would think that a relatively small current was drawn from the battery so it's probably fine. If your meter seems to still measure resistances correctly then I would say you dodged the bullet. What will certainly blow a fuse in your meter is to set it for a current measurement and attach the leads directly to such a battery.

Comment: If it's not obviously damaged, it probably isn't. I'm not sure I'd use it to power a spacecraft or life support device, but otherwise you are probably just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I put it on the charger, its voltage was still what I would have expected and the cells were balanced, and it charged correctly. It seems okay, I'm going to use it (for an R/C helicopter).

Comment: Is there a "collective" resource that lists all the absolute do-nots of multimetering? I hear to never mix ____ and _____ when metering, and so forth, but don't have a good grasp on the do-nots as a whole. I'd ask it as a question, but I worry that it'd get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Most meters will have a fused input, an unfused input (usually for the high current range), and a common input.  Shorting the battery should blow the fuse - so if your meter is working, you should be fine.